# What does the DEBUG statement do?

Tags: c++, nachos

I am studying nachos for a university project and can't understand what the DEBUG(...) statement in the below code is doing.

```
void
ThreadTest1()
{
   DEBUG('t', "Entering ThreadTest1");
   Thread *t = new Thread("forked thread");
   t->Fork(SimpleThread, 1);
   SimpleThread(0);
}
```

Can someone please help ?

Comment: http://www.cs.duke.edu/~chase/cps110-archive/nachos-guide/nachos-labs-13.html

Comment: C doesn't have a `new` operator. Please tag questions with the correct language. C is not C++.

Comment: re-tagged. thanks for pointing in out

Comment: Check in your project It may be a pre-processor code #defined some where .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DEBUG is a conditional print statement that is activated when you run your code with "-d" option, as in $nachos -d ti. There are a few debug flags, for example "t" enables printing (debugging) of thread events, which you think you're after by your code snippet.

Comment: so what is the purpose of the second parameter "Entering ThreadTest1"

Comment: ohh, does it simply say "Entering ThreadTest1" before printing everything else ?

Comment: It will print it at some point, yes. Thats the concept of debugging by printing - to analyze the sequence of events in your program by looking at whats been printed out. Hope that helps.